# Multiple websites in one database?

Tags: mysql, database, installation

I am building a website templating system where multiple user can create their own mini-websites.  I anticipate the possibility of this system scaling to millions of users. Is it best to store all data for everyone's mini-site in one MySQL database, or create a separate MySQL database for each user?

What is the setup to handle future scalability to millions of users? What are the pros and cons of each option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy to have millions of records in one database, and impossible to handle millions of databases in one (or a few) computer.

If you really have few data for each user, and really plan to have many users, don't even try to give each user its database. A database is made to grow and handle many records.

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 2):

Working backwards... creating 1 million database instances will not be very practical.

So yes, you probably want to use at least a much smaller number of databases.  This class of problem is known as a [Multi-Tenant Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy).

If you store a few thousand entries per website, you will find that MySQL takes you pretty far with a single database (plus at least one slave for backups and failover...).

At some point, you will want to setup a second Master / Slave DB pair to handle the next batch of customers.